# APNS is always received but payload is always nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I'm having a problem with APNS where the notification is received on the device but the payload userInfo is always nil:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
      fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
```

I can see in the debugger this is always called but userInfo is always nil.  This is the payload I'm sending via PyAPNS:

```
{"aps":{"content-available":1},"extradata":"extra data string"}
```

This will do nothing, debugger shows that receiver is executed but userInfo is nil.  If I background the app and send this packet:

```
{"aps":{"alert":"My Alert", "content-available":1},"extradata":"extra data string"}
```

Then the alert will be displayed in the notifications area and the receiver is executed but userInfo is still nil.

Has anyone experienced something similar?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a provisioning problem.  I had a manually created dev provisioning profile that I was using.  I deleted that profile and xcode auto-created on (labeled as "managed by xcode" in itunes connect under provision profiles) and it started working.  I didn't imagine this was a provision/cert issue because only the custom vars weren't being delivered, but I guess this solved the issue.